# Can I restrict cfmail to only send mail from a given domain using cf admin

Tags: coldfusion, smtp, coldfusion-10, cfmail

We have had issues with our server being used to send spam via cfmail to our remote SMTP server.  I cannot see where it is occurring, but the emails are sent from a domain that is not one on our server.

Is there a way using ColdFusion administrator to specify that only emails showing as from someone@mydomain.com are sent to the SMTP host via the spool?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: This really rather sounds like something you should be controlling at the mail server.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like you need to fix the vulnerability that is allowing someone to execute CF on your behalf. That is absolutely insane. Restricting domains wouldn't fix your spam issue either because they could simply use _your_ domain.

Comment: Are you certain that the questionable emails are being sent from CF? Is it possible they are accessing the SMTP server directly? Check you CF mail logs to verify if they are coming from CF or not.

Comment: CF logs definitely show the mail going through ColdFusion.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like the `<cfmail>` side of things here is a red herring and you have got an open relay on your mail server. You seriously need to disable that immediately! If your SMTP server has to relay email *for your CFML app* then make sure it's not configured to relay *everything*, instead just for the IP address of the CF server, or for the credentials the CF server uses to connect to it.

If you don't know how to configure the relaying settings for your SMTP server, raise another question on serverfault.com asking how. Provide the exact details of your SMTP server, as well as the requirement to still allow relaying for the CF server.

Comment: Mail is being sent via Coldfusion (log files show that the mails in the CF mail logs).  It looks as though they found a way in previously through an un-patched Wordpress fault (last year).  Wordpress was patched and it stopped until last week.  Wordpress has now been removed but I am looking to make it as dificult as I can should they manage to get through again.  The login info for the smtp server is stored in the CF admin but cf admin is not accessible externally.

Comment: Well the problem then is simply that people got access to run CFML on your CF server. How do you expect either the SMTP server or the CF server itself to be able to distinguish between your sanctioned code, and a hacker's dodgy code? All the code is being run on the CF server, after all. You're probably better off investing time running hackmycf.com and other environment-hardening exercises than trying to protect against this which is just a symptom of the broader - and more critical - issue.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I understand that the problem is that there has been the ability to run CFML, however while I investigate that, I assumed that as what they were doing with cfmail was very specific in terms of the sending email address, restricting it would at least prevent more mail from going until I have got to the bottom of it all.